# Magento connect manager error "Unsupported resource type" when uploading *.tgz package

Tags: php, magento, installation, package

We developed a magento extension and it seems to be working just fine but suddenly a couple of customers contacted us stating that they get an error when trying to install our extension by uploading *.tgz package through magento connect manager.

The error in the console says: `CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type`

I think this might be somehow related to archiving/dearchiving process but I'm not quite sure.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

They also said that other extensions installed fine. As well as our extension installed fine to many others.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

After more customers complained about this I tried some more cases out. It looks like the package was somehow corrupted. I would find everything the way it should be after extracting the package manually but the magento connect manager couldn't somehow detect headers in the archive file.

I solved it by repackaging same files once again using another magento copy but why this is happening stays unclear.

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/795992/

Comment: I ran into this thread last time but this wasn't the case. Now I don't have the FTP access yet

Answer (score 0):

have you try use direct extension downloader? such as

```
http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php
```

Comment: Well as I get it this would only let me download the package to install it directly. I do already have the package. The problem is it won't install through magento connect manager by browsing the extension file and uploading it.

Comment: i think i misunderstanding you question, ignore my answer